# Trigger Not working but record is inserted in phpmyadmin

Tags: jsp, phpmyadmin, innodb

Team,

I have created a trigger which updates another table ;when a record is inserted on one table. i.e when issue of a item happen issued quantity is deducted from stock table i.e  new stock quantity  =  existing stock quantity- issued stock quantity

I see a new record is inserted and trigger is invoked when i do isnert via a SQL command.

But record is inserted trigger is not invoked when i do it via my JSP application.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_user_1 AFTER INSERT ON cartridge_issue
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE cartridge_status 
   SET cartridge_status.stock = (cartridge_status.stock - NEW.qnty_issu‌​ed) 
WHERE cartridge_status.cart_name = NEW.cart_name
```

What could be wrong i wonder? Please help

Comment: Share your trigger code.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_user_1` AFTER INSERT ON `cartridge_issue`
 FOR EACH ROW update cartridge_status set cartridge_status.stock=(cartridge_status.stock-NEW.qnty_issued) where cartridge_status.cart_name =NEW. cart_name

Comment: Also you need to share insert code, `cartridge_issue` and `cartridge_status` entities if they requires

Comment: Hi Hakan, Its a batch update  using PreparedStatement ;mystatement = null;

Comment: mydbStatement = con.prepareStatement(query); 
          while(loop<size)
          {
 
           
           mydbStatement.setString(1,updatevalues.get(loop+3).toString()); 
           mydbStatement.setString(2,updatevalues.get(loop+4).toString());  
           mydbStatement.setString(3,updatevalues.get(loop+5).toString()); 
           
           loop =loop+3;
          }
          
          res = mydbStatement .executeBatch();  records are properly inserted on needed table

Comment: According to your code ( we could not see your query string or cart_name field ) everything seems normal so there is one chance left your trigger condition (`WHERE cartridge_status.cart_name = NEW.cart_name` )  is not true that means there is no record in `cartridge_status` table for `NEW.cart_name`

Comment: what i feel is that only  once trigger is invoked for the entire batch. what my current trigger deals with is only one record of the table...suppose in my batch 5 rows are inserted and trigger is invoked once....i am seeing records are getting inserted on needed table ....only thing is trigger to update a related table doesnt works

Comment: what i think i need to do is to iterate the inserted records list